# How to insert special characters in TDengine?

Tags: sql, tdengine

I tried to create a table using the following sql clause but syntax error is reported. I suspect the columns like "x-axis" "y-axis" have special character hypen in their names, but how can I make TDengine accept special characters in column names?

```
taos> create table tt (ts timestamp, x-axis double, y-axis double);

DB error: syntax error near "-axis double, y-axis double);" (0.019247s)
taos>
```

Comment: In the SQL standard, you need quoted identifiers (enclosed in double quotes) to allow such characters (i.e. `"x-axis"`), some database systems use backticks (i.e. `\`x-axis\``), or square brackets (i.e. `[x-axis]`). Check the TDEngine documentation if it supports quoted identifiers, and if so what quote character it uses.

Comment: While escaping special characters is usually an option, I found that avoiding special characters is often much easier to do without headache. (That does not mean the question is useless because you can't always choose and control such names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try it with back quote like this:

```
create table tt (ts timestamp, `x-axis` double, `y-axis` double);
```